# How to segment the connected area based on depth color to python

Tags: python, matlab, opencv

I am trying to segment depth images using opencv and python. I came across the code below. it is written in matlab. I need some help with converting matlab script to python (opencv). any help or advice is appreciated. orignial link is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45247717/how-to-segment-the-connected-area-based-on-depth-color-in-opencv)

```
img = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lJw8.png');  % read the image
depth = double(img(:,:,1));
depth(depth==255)=-100;  % make the background VERY distinct
[dy dx] = gradient(depth);  % compute depth gradients
bmsk = sqrt(dx.^2+dy.^2) > 5;  % consider only significant gradient
% using morphological operations to "complete" the contours around the cars
bmsk = bwmorph( bwmorph(bmsk, 'dilate', ones(7)), 'skel'); 

% once the contours are complete, use connected components
cars = bwlabel(~bmsk,4);  % segmentation mask
st = regionprops(cars, 'Area', 'BoundingBox');
% display the results
figure;
imshow(img);
hold all;
for ii=2:numel(st),  % ignore the first segment - it's the background
    if st(ii).Area>200, % ignore small regions as "noise"
        rectangle('Position',st(ii).BoundingBox, 'LineWidth', 3, 'EdgeColor', 'g');
    end;
end;
```

Comment: The only part of this code that doesn't have a built-in function in OpenCV is skeletonization, which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33095476/is-there-any-build-in-function-can-do-skeletonization-in-opencv). Please identify specific portions of the code that you are having trouble with and what research you have done to understand those portions.

Comment: Actually, looking at the other answer in the question I linked, it appears that skeletonization is now included in OpenCV as `thinning()`.

Comment: @beaker I haven't written any code yet, as I am having trouble understanding which OpenCV/python modules fits each line. I dont know how to define these two lines in python: depth = double(img(:,:,1)); depth(depth==255)=-100;